# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (in WPF)

Tags: wpf, vb.net

```
private Sub Btn_Show_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
       Dim dt As New DataTable()
       Dim SearchCriteria = cmbSearch.Text
       dt.Columns.Add("Title", GetType(String))
       dt.Columns.Add("Author", GetType(String))
       dt.Columns.Add("AccessionNo", GetType(String))
       dt.Columns.Add("Location", GetType(String))
       dt.Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))
       Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument()
       xmldoc.Load("C:\Users\Shahrukh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Simple search1\Simple search1\New folder\Data.xml")
       Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/NewDataSet/Table")


       If SearchCriteria = "Title" Then
           For Each node As XmlNode In nodeList
               Dim dtrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
               If (LCase(node("title").InnerText).Contains(LCase(txtSearch.Text()))) Then
                   dtrow("Title") = node("title").InnerText
                   dtrow("Author") = node("Author").InnerText
                   dtrow("AccessionNo") = node("AccessionNo").InnerText
                   dtrow("Location") = node("location").InnerText
                   dtrow("Status") = node("status").InnerText
                   dt.Rows.Add(dtrow)
               End If
           Next
       End If

       If SearchCriteria = "Author" Then
           For Each nodeAuthor As XmlNode In nodeList
               Dim dtrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
               If (LCase(nodeAuthor("Author").InnerText).Contains(LCase(txtSearch.Text()))) Then
                   dtrow("title") = nodeAuthor("title").InnerText
                   dtrow("Author") = nodeAuthor("Author").InnerText
                   dtrow("AccessionNo") = nodeAuthor("AccessionNo").InnerText
                   dtrow("location") = nodeAuthor("location").InnerText
                   dtrow("status") = nodeAuthor("status").InnerText
                   dt.Rows.Add(dtrow)
               End If
           Next
       End If
       dGridResults.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
   End Sub
```

It gives an Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: can you tell me whats a problem in shown code that 's  a such a big help for me to tell that and how to correct it

Comment: Can you show your xml setup? My guess is that you are not fetching any object with your xPath. Which would make the nodelist null.

Comment: yes i will add it i will add hole code here

Comment: exactly tell me now what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see an inconsistency. You have a Table with the column "Title". In node/nodeAuthor you fetch "title" both times (so I figure that is ok). But for dtRow you write to "Title" in the first if and "title" in the second. Change that to "Title" and  try again.

```
               dtrow("Title") = node("title").InnerText
```

Comment: still the error is on and that point to the "If (LCase(nodeAuthor("author").InnerText).Contains(LCase(txtSearch.Text()))) Then"